# Scalable Business Logic Rules

Tags: c#, rules, business-objects

I am looking for a way to create a scalable sales order project where it is easy to append new business rules.

```
public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Line { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public int LeadTimeDays { get; set; }        
    public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
}
```

What are best practices for creating business rules to check that an order line is valid?  And, is there an easy way to apply multiple rules without adding a check method for each one?

```
public static class OrderLineChecks
{
    public static void CheckLeadTime(this OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        if( (orderLine.ShipDate - DateTime.Today).TotalDays < orderLine.LeadTimeDays )
            throw new Exception("Order is within lead time.");
    }

    public static void CheckShipDateError(this OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        if(orderLine.ShipDate < DateTime.Today)
            throw new Exception("Ship date cannot be before today.");
    }
    public static void ShouldBeOrderedInPairs(this OrderLine orderLine)
    {
        if(orderLine.Description.Contains("pair") && (orderLine.Quantity % 2 !=0))
            throw new Exception("Quantities must be even numbers.");
    }
    public static NextFutureRuleHere(...)
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Why not have a single void CheckBusinessRules() and then place each of your business rule if statements inside of that method?

Comment: Because that wouldn't be fun to test would it?

Comment: It sounds like you want the .NET validation elements in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute or something similar?

Comment: Your intuition should be that if you need to manipulate a concept as a  first-class value, make a bunch of objects, starting with something like an `IRule`, and some sort of set of those. (This object might as well be a delegate type and an array thereof for aggregation, if you're willing to make changing the signature more difficult later.)

Comment: Are the validation rules supposed to be client-configurable?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Fluent Validation: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Following how this framework implements rules should help you work out what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Or think about the .NET version that uses attributes so that you don't have to really think about it, or code it, except right on the data model? System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute

Comment: @jcolebrand The idea of Fluent Validation is that sometimes you don't want this stuff shoved in the model, not "we have no clue Data Annotations exist". Think checks that are done against a layer that the model has no business contacting directly. E.g. stock levels maintained in an ERP system where the order app only has weak references by product ID into it. Data Annotations looks more suited to expressing invariants that the model has to satisfy, it seems like more dynamic checks would end up bloating the model too much.

Comment: Ok, that's valid, to an extent. I don't want my business layer checking that my lengths are not too long, nor that start date comes before end date, those are model concerns. Validate the right thing in the right place.

Comment: The Fluent Validation looks interesting.  I was thinking along the lines of delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements it might be overkill, but have you considered writing up a DSL with [Rhino DSL & Boo](https://github.com/ayende/rhino-dsl)  .  Quite easy to [expand / maintain](http://ayende.com/blog/3764/should-you-be-able-to-define-new-abstractions-in-a-domain-specific-language) a [set of business rules](http://ayende.com/blog/3740/the-shopping-cart-rule-engine-dsl) even by non-programmers if you code it right.